# How to place label at the end of arrow in mscgen

Tags: mscgen

I need to place the labels at the end and not in the middle by default. Any option for that is available?

Comment: did you try to Google it?

Comment: ya. but couldn't get an answer

Comment: There is no such option in mscgen at the moment. What is your use case for placing labels (assuming for arcs/ arrows) at the end? Does your diagram become hard to read without them? (I'm asking because I rewrote  mscgen in javascript (https://mscgen.js.org) and am interested in improving it based on real world use)